# cuSPARSE dense times sparse

Tags: cuda, sparse-matrix

I need to calculate the following matrix math:
D * A
Where D is dense, and A is sparse, in CSC format.
cuSPARSE allows multiplying sparse * dense, where sparse matrix is in CSR format.
Following a related question, I can "convert" CSC to CSR simply by transposing A.
Also I can calculate (A^T * D^T)^T, as I can handle getting the result transposed.
In this method I can also avoid "transposing" A, because CSR^T is CSC.
The only problem is that cuSPARSE doesn't support transposing D in this operation, so I have to tranpose it beforehand, or convert it to CSR, which is a total waste, as it is **very** dense.

Is there any workaround?
Thanks.

Comment: Probably you know this already, but you can transpose a dense matrix in cublas using the [geam](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#topic_9_1) function.

Comment: Is this a stand alone operation or are you doing something on the lines of `A' * D * A` ?

Comment: The operation is X - D * A
where X & D are very dense and A is very sparse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround.
I changed the memory accesses to D in my entire code.
If D is an mxn matrix, and I used to access it by `D[j * m + i]`, now I'm accessing it by `D[i * n + j]`, meaning I made it rows-major instead of columns-major.
cuSPARSE expectes matrices in column-major format, and because rows-major transposed is columns-major, I can pass D to cuSPARSE functions as a fake transpose without the need to make the transpose.